# Parse java.time trying multiple patterns

Tags: java, java-time

We have a library where users can pass in dates in multiple formats. They follow the ISO but are abbreviated at times.

So we get things like "19-3-12" and "2019-03-12T13:12:45.1234" where the fractional seconds can be 1 - 7 digits long. It's a very large number of combinations.

DateTimeFormatter.parseBest doesn't work because it won't accept "yy-m-d" for a local date. [The solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49812003/java-time-datetimeformatter-parsing-with-flexible-fallback-values) won't work because it assumes we know the pattern - we don't.

And telling people to get their string formats "correct" won't work as there's a ton of existing data (these are mostly in XML & JSON files).

My question is, how can I parse strings coming in in these various pattersn without have to try 15 different explicit patterns?

Or even better, is there some way to parse a string and it will try everything possible and return a Temporal object if the string makes sense for any date[time]?

Comment: OK. But... what is your question?

Comment: @JBNizet - Sorry, explicit question added to the end now.

Comment: You're excluding the simplest solution. Just do that.

Comment: @JBNizet I think calling 15 times is going to be slow. There are a lot of code paths where we try to parse to see if a string is a datetime. Usually it isn't. So we then have 15 attempts and that takes time.

Comment: @DavidThielen if the date order is always `y-m-d` you might as well parse it manually.
Split on `T`, then first token on `-` and second token on `:` if you have one

Comment: I doubt that has a significant impact on the performance. You shouldn't exclude the obvious, simple solution just because you think it's going to be slow. Only optimize after you're proven that it caused a performance problem.

Comment: @DavidThielen If you ask if there is a magic way to guess the format : no, there isn't. Either you format individually each date assuming that all dates coming from a given source are formatted uniformly, or you try 15 patterns in a sequence (from most secure to most ambiguous pattern) until one matches.

Comment: You can speed it up by adding a bit of complexity, but before doing that, measure and prove that it causes a performance problem. One way of speeding things up would be to only try the patterns which have a length equal/compatible with the length of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a full specification it is hard to give a precise recommendation. The techniques generally used for variable formats include:

1. Trying a number of known formats in turn.
2. Optional parts in the format pattern.
3. `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.parseDefaulting()` for parts that may be absent from the parsed string.
4. As you are aware, `parseBest`.

I am assuming that y-M-d always come in this order (never M-d-y or d-M-y, for example). `19-3-12` conflicts with ISO 8601 since the standard requires (at least) 4 digit year and 2 digit month. A challenge with 2-digit year is guessing the century: is this 1919 or 2019 or might it be 2119?

The good news: presence and absence of seconds and varying number of fractional digits are all built-in and pose no problem.

From what you have told us it seems to me that the following is a fair shot.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("[uuuu][uu]-M-d")
            .optionalStart()
            .appendLiteral('T')
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .optionalEnd()
            .toFormatter();

    TemporalAccessor dt = formatter.parseBest("19-3-12", LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
    System.out.println(dt.getClass());
    System.out.println(dt);
```

Output:

> ```
> class java.time.LocalDate
> 2019-03-12
> ```

I figure that it should work with the variations of formats that you describe. Let’s just try your other example:

```
    dt = formatter.parseBest( "2019-03-12T13:12:45.1234", LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
    System.out.println(dt.getClass());
    System.out.println(dt);
```

> ```
> class java.time.LocalDateTime
> 2019-03-12T13:12:45.123400
> ```

To control the interpretation of 2-digit year you may use one of the overloaded variants of [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendValueReduced()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendValueReduced(java.time.temporal.TemporalField,int,int,java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)). I recommend that you consider a range check on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Trying all the possible formats would perform worse than trying only 15.

You can try to "normalize" to a single format but then you would be doing the work those 15 formats are supposed to do.

I think the best approach is the one described by @JB Nizet, to try only patterns that match string length.

```
public Date parse(String openFormat) { 
    String[] formats = {"YYY-MM-DD"};
    switch(openFormat.length()) {
       case 24: // 2019-03-12T13:12:45.1234
             formats = new String[]{"YYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssetcetc", }; // all the formats for length 24
             break;
       ...
       case 6: //YYY-MM-DD, DD-MM-YYYY
             formats = new String[]{YYY-MM-DD", "DD-MM-YYYY", }; // all the formats for length 6
             break;
      }
      Date myDate
      // now try the reduced number of formats, possibly only 1 or 2
      for( String format : formats) try {
          myDate = date parse ( format ) etcetc
      } catch (DateFormatException d) {
          continue;
      } 
      if (myDate == null){
         throw InvalidDate
      } else {
      return myDate
      }
 }
```